# Regex for checking if URL has certain format

Tags: c#, regex

oI have the following code that is trying to validate if a URL is of a certain format:
I have come up with this regex but due to my lack of experience with it I cant seem to figure out what exactly is wrong with it.

The regex is to have all URLs with http/https, www/Bil/Qc, product.company, qc1/qc2/com.

Anyone see anything wrong with this, it should match it correctly:

```
string origin = "https://bil-product.company.com/";
Regex reg = new Regex("(http[s]?://)+(BIL|QC)*product.company.(qc1|qc2|com)", RegexOptions.Singleline & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (reg.IsMatch(origin))
{
    //Do thangs with codes and stuff
}
```

Comment: in regex `dot` has special meaning. escape it.

Comment: This doesn't even compile. What's going on with that first line? Should `ReturnUrl=...;` be on its own line? (In that case, `string origin = "..."` needs to end with a `;`, and the `ReturnUrl` string needs to be surrounded by `"`.)

Comment: Do you know what the issue is? Does it match things it shouldn't, or does it miss things it should match?

Comment: @Jashaszun Not entirely sure how that got there, Edited my question to include the right URL.

Comment: @Antoine It should match it, sorry should have included that as part of the question.

Comment: Are those the only nine things you are searching for? Meaning only [`http`], [`https`], [`www`], [`Bil`], [`Qc`], [`product.company`], [`qc1`], [`qc2`], and [`com`].

Comment: this ?: has special meaning also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `RegexOptions.Singleline`. It looks like you forgot the "www" and ending "/" parts in your regex. If you want to make sure that there is an exact match to only the desired string, you can use `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the string repectively, so...

```
string[] origins = { "http://qc-product.company.com/",
                       "https://www.company.com/",
                       "https://bil-product.company.com/",
                       "http://company.com/",
                       "http://www.example.com/",
                       "http://www.company.com/example.html" };

Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(http[s]?://)(www|((BIL|QC)-product))\.company\.(qc1|qc2|com)/$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (string origin in origins)
{
    Console.Write(origin + " ");
    Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch(origin) ? "match" : "not");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

outputs:

```
http://qc-product.company.com/ match
https://www.company.com/ match
https://bil-product.company.com/ match
http://company.com/ not
http://www.example.com/ not
http://www.company.com/example.html not
```

Comment: Huh yeah I forgot about that, let me do some testing.

Comment: So this is the optimal answer with the www included which I had forgotten. I did change it slightly to allow urls such as https://www.product.company.com, (http[s]?://)(www\.|((BIL|QC)-))product\.company\.(qc1|qc2|com)

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression matches:

```
(http[s]?://)+(BIL|QC).*product\.company\.(qc1|qc2|com)
```

You forgot about `-` sign before `product`. I've replaced `*` (not sure why you used it there) with `-`. But there are some other issues:

1. It won't work because options must be "`OR`ed", not "`AND`ed" (`AND` resets flags):

   ```
   Regex reg = new Regex(..., RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   ```
2. Why `(http[s]?://)+` this allows this pattern to occur one or *more* times, so your pattern matches `https://https://bil-product.company.com/`

Comment: This is the right answer, I removed the + as well, to be honest I thought it was for adding it to the regex, I need to scrub up on this stuff but for the moment I just needed this done before I can do so.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you use the OR-operator | when combining the regex flags at the end? Maybe `RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` would do the trick. Maybe your code will not use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` due to the AND-operator.

Along with the other problems the following code will work:

```
string origin = "https://bil-product.company.com/";
Regex reg = new Regex("(http[s]?://)((BIL|QC)-)?product\\.company\\.(qc1|qc2|com)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (reg.IsMatch(origin))
{
    //Do things with codes and stuff
}
```

- I removed the + behind the protocol-prefix. Why you would allow multiple http-prefixes?
- I added the - behind (BIL|QC)
- I replaced * by ? behind the (BIL|QC)-part cause I assumed that this part should not occur multiple times (if I'm wrong feel free to revert the change)
- I escaped the dots
- I fixed the flag combining